# Example/Explanation on chrome.sockets.udp multicasting

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am making an Chrome app which will have a 'chat' feature (like what [this app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multicast-chat-sample/bnheobjndkaipbloffigkiddhcbblihl) has). When a user joins the chat (by connecting to a port), the user would receive all messages that were created during his/her session. However, although I understand most of [the app's code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/multicast), I couldn't understand how the multicasting part of the code exactly works.

From what I understand, this is how it should go:

```
var socket = 0;
chrome.sockets.udp.create({bufferSize: 1024 * 1024}, function (createInfo) //Create socket entry
{
   socket = createInfo.socketId;
   console.log(socket); //This works - tells me an integer
   var ttl = 12;
   chrome.sockets.udp.setMulticastTimeToLive(socket, ttl, function (result)
   {
      if(result < 0)
      {
        console.log("MULTICAST FAILED" + result);
      }
      else
      {
        chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socket, "0.0.0.0", 8080, function(result) //Bind to socket
        {
          if(result < 0)
          {
            console.log("BIND FAILED" + result);
            chrome.sockets.udp.close(socket);
          }
          else
          {
            chrome.sockets.udp.joinGroup(socket, "237.132.123.123", function(result) //join Multicast group
            {
              if(result < 0)
              {
                console.log("Couldn't join Group!");
                chrome.sockets.udp.close(socket);
              }
              else
              {
                console.log("GOT HERE");          //Outputs this

                chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(function(msg)  //Listen for receiving messages
                {
                  console.log(msg.socketId);
                })
                chrome.sockets.udp.onReceiveError.addListener(function(error)   //If error while receiving, do this
                {
                  console.log(error.socketId + " " + error.resultCode);
                });
              }
            })
          }
        });


      }
    })


  })
//Later in the code (linked to a button I press (and when app closes)
chrome.sockets.udp.close(socket);
```

The problem with this is that although the code reaches the callback function of .send() (which should mean that it sent successfully), I also get errors while binding saying that the socket doesn't exist (although I created it and the socket number outputted an integer). When I make two application with the same code as above and try to make them listen/send to each other, neither gets the message.

Can someone provide a clear example (no gui code, no runtime messaging) which illustrates how to multicast correctly using the newer chrome.sockets.udp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to deal with this, your code should work if you include this in your manifest:

```
"sockets": {
    "udp": {
        "send": ["*"],
        "bind": ["*"],
        "multicastMembership": [""]
    }
}
```

If you already did, try changing your port / address in case your network is already using them. If that still doesn't work, try removing the options on create() and see if anything happens.

Sorry if I'm too late.

Comment: Its fine. I did it a while ago, but forgot to update this question. =)